# Lifetime in Iterator: fn next(&'a mut self)

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

```
struct Person<T> {
    letter: Letter<T>
}

struct Letter<T> {
    words: [Option<T>; 5]
}

struct EditIter<'a, T: 'a> {
    letter: &'a mut Letter<T>
}
impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for EditIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = Mode<'a, T>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        /* ... */
        Some(Mode::Editing(self.letter))
    }
}

enum Mode<'a, T: 'a> {
    Editing(&'a Letter<T>),
    Speaking(&'a Letter<T>)
}
```

Error:

```
src/temp.rs:16:28: 16:39 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/temp.rs:16         Some(Mode::Editing(self.letter))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/temp.rs:14:5: 17:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
src/temp.rs:14     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
src/temp.rs:15         /* ... */
src/temp.rs:16         Some(Mode::Editing(self.letter))
src/temp.rs:17     }
```

`Person` owns the `Letter`, `Person` transfers a mutable borrow of `Letter` to `EditIter`, `EditIter` creates a `Mode` with the borrowed `Letter` and sends it. If you remove the `Iterator` trait and do as written in the error message, it works, but this would not implement the `Iterator` trait.

How can I save the logic and fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Mode` doesn't have any need for a mutable reference, remove the `mut` from `EditIter` and it will work:

```
struct Person<T> {
    letter: Letter<T>,
}

struct Letter<T> {
    words: [Option<T>; 5],
}

struct EditIter<'a, T: 'a> {
    letter: &'a Letter<T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for EditIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = Mode<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(Mode::Editing(self.letter))
    }
}

enum Mode<'a, T: 'a> {
    Editing(&'a Letter<T>),
    Speaking(&'a Letter<T>),
}
```

Comment: **`EditIter` should be able to change the `Letter`. (for example, `words`).** `Mode` - component of the external  API. The `Letter` has some public methods.

Comment: @nujemid I'm not sure what to tell you. Based on the [MCVE](/help/mcve) and descriptive text that you provided in the question, the code compiles and runs with the changes I've made.

Comment: @nujemid: then... it might be that your MCVE is not C (Complete)? You have much more context that we do (obviously), and we cannot pry it from your mind, so please include all necessary details in the example code.